# How do I get ethereum transactions?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I'm getting started to Ethereum and Web3py and I would like to get transactions happening whenever they happen on a [specific address](https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d&__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=f0f49f7b3123f0aaacde1b354ce05b09a4b56bc7-1613383659-0-AT9smBzL4c9A5Ra3NhnhXPb8siE0cJGZUVJ15cct1-odbdY7qNy6inhNz_iLxDxG4_xTANua8dGxmNGL_1bvctyh27wp588Or35i9naXbGgp7exsaI5T8RvH_h2r9BqsHfSQwzcjFfzBc9CwEEgdTnSgHer8FIPHloVze_2JVCy1He7e18cd3taERx3xQC_PZIEbQHyyVUZ3zm8vCULqqSqmKoc8oquSwQHh91QpYhw6SGfQ-GdI0E4AsBHvE-SxHAistXNXJHF8clXR_h6cJO-gwE8mqQ9t_IDuuxCkkcndjkG6joOpCwmYLFC3FksVZMWvE3Va4TJ6I_bKFlBG-ehFkrCDDo_Ta2ST-OiOsbI0WZ5l8vXE0nL4yEJVSdoRwg). In order to do this, I signed up to infura and got my project ID. So here is what I tried:

```
from web3 import Web3
import asyncio
import websockets

ABI = {"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountADesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveB","type":"uint256"}],"name":"quote","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapETHForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}

def handle_event(event):
    # Define data from the event
    print(event)


async def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter:
            handle_event(event)
        await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)

def main():
    w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(f'wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/<MY-PRIJECT>'))
    uniswap = w3.eth.contract('0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D', abi=ABI)
    block_filter = uniswap.events.getLogs.createFilter(fromBlock = 'latest').get_all_entries()
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(log_loop(block_filter, 2)))
    finally:
        loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The response is  this: `("The event 'getLogs' was not found in this contract's abi. ", 'Are you sure you provided the correct contract abi?')`

I also tried to do this using Infura:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def connect():
    uri = "wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/<MY-PROJECT>"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as ws:
        await ws.send('{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["logs", {"address": "0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d"}]}')

        while True:
            msg = await ws.recv()
            message = json.loads(msg)
            print(message)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connect())
```

But this gives me nothing.

How can I get messages as soon as a new transaction is made and get the ETH amount for that transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/16113/60070), it is simpler/faster to use a centralized tool like the [Etherscan API](https://etherscan.io/apis) to do such a task.

Assuming this solution suits you, it is then quite simple to get what you're looking for:

```python
import json
import time

import requests

# Place your own Etherscan API key here
ETHERSCAN_API_KEY =

ADDRESS = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"

def get_last_block():
    return int(json.loads(requests.get(
        f"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=block&action=getblocknobytime&timestamp={round(time.time())}&closest=before&apikey={ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}"
    ).text)["result"])

def get_last_txs(since=2):
    return json.loads(requests.get(
        f"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address={ADDRESS}&startblock={get_last_block() - since}&sort=asc&apikey={ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}"
    ).text)["result"] 

txs = get_last_txs()
```

In a shell, you would get the following behavior:

```python
>>> type(txs)
<class 'list'>
>>> len(txs)
60
>>> txs[0]
{'blockNumber': '11887758', 'timeStamp': '1613743087', 'hash': '0xacb6ba33c7fc4d8db7ad8ba4b09263ed0e6c2050842d189ba09b8a06b81ebc32', 'nonce': '25', 'blockHash': '0xebf1b16b9bccfb2dab43a304dfe2fb3d6c80d714669fd7bb651af98d497ddbea', 'transactionIndex': '56', 'from': '0xd8f19c1fd2916e10f0460976e57251d5a42e394f', 'to': '0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d', 'value': '0', 'gas': '198839', 'gasPrice': '191000000000', 'isError': '0', 'txreceipt_status': '1', 'input': '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', 'contractAddress': '', 'cumulativeGasUsed': '3396885', 'gasUsed': '155481', 'confirmations': '3'}
>>> txs[-1]
{'blockNumber': '11887760', 'timeStamp': '1613743113', 'hash': '0x6228f262db37a2eeaba16869e45cb0e632bb1a2f301bda57fd9c7c54a2abe26b', 'nonce': '763', 'blockHash': '0x3352a2613fd38d1a4e90d8cac7f89df6f0fdfe3b9b7f20557b7d60b2e3fd643e', 'transactionIndex': '214', 'from': '0xe4fb9ca52e39b83be69e74e7fac8f807a9c16ef9', 'to': '0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d', 'value': '0', 'gas': '174926', 'gasPrice': '148832420000', 'isError': '1', 'txreceipt_status': '0', 'input': '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', 'contractAddress': '', 'cumulativeGasUsed': '11747610', 'gasUsed': '23683', 'confirmations': '1'}
```

You are then free to do whatever you want with these transactions. Of course, you can look up the Etherscan API to get any additional info you would like to get. Be careful though, since you are limited to 5 requests/s. This is why the `since` parameter could show useful: you can make 1 request every 10 seconds, but by considering the last 2 or 3 blocks, you are sure not to miss a transaction. You also have to consider the fact that the API returns at most 10000 transactions, so you have to get them 10000 by 10000 if you want a complete history of transactions on this contract.

If this is not what you're looking for, please tell me and I'll be happy to delete my answer.

Comment: Yes, using Etherscan is indeed a good solution. The only con is the rate limit, but i can work on that. Thank you a lot!